# Spring SQLUpdate inserts Date with zero time into DB

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I am using an org.springframework.jdbc.object.SqlUpdate to insert a Date into a DB. I am using HSQL for local testing and Oracle for testing on a server.

This is my SQLUpdate-Class:

```
private class SQLInsertHistory extends SqlUpdate implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SQLInsertHistory(DataSource ds) {
        setDataSource(ds);
        setSql(INSERT_HISTORY_ENTRY);
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.DATE)); // EXECUTING_DATE
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR)); // EXECUTING_USER
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR)); // FILENAME
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR)); // MD5_CHECKSUM
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.INTEGER)); // SUCCESSFULL_FLAG
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.INTEGER)); // NEW_INSTITUTION_FLAG
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR)); // FREE_TEXT
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR)); // ENTRY_TYPE
        compile();
    }

public void insertHistoryEntry(HistoryEntryContainer entry) {

        Object[] values = new Object[] { 
                new java.sql.Date(entry.getDate().getTime()), // EXECUTING_DATE
                entry.getExecutingUser(), // EXECUTING_USER
                entry.getFileName(), // FILENAME,
                entry.getMd5(), // MD5_CHECKSUM
                (entry.isSuccess() ? 1 : 0), // SUCCESSFULL_FLAG
                (entry.isNewInstitution() ? 1 : 0), // NEW_INSTITUTION_FLAG
                entry.getFreeText(), // FREE_TEXT
                entry.getType().toString() };
        update(values);
        log.debug((entry.isSuccess() ? "Successfull " : "Unsuccessfull ")
                + entry.getType().toString() + " of File "
                + entry.getFileName() + " recorded in DB.");
    }

}
```

Now the execution is working fine, but it always stores the Date with hours, minutes and seconds = 0. Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Types.DATE` which includes only `DATE` and not TIME, Use [`Types.TIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#TIMESTAMP)

Use : `new java.sql.Timestamp(entry.getDate().getTime())` to convert time into timestamp at the place of `new java.sql.Date(entry.getDate().getTime()), // EXECUTING_DATE`